# How do I limit string length using Javascript .replace() with a regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to limit a zip code to 5 and digits with a replace()
I have googled many variations of the expression.

```
$('#ZIP').on('keyup', function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[\D]{5}$/g, ''));
});
```

I have tried these and many more:
`/\D{5}/g`
`/[\D]{5}/g`
`/([\D]){5}/g`
`/[^0-9]{5}/g`

Then all of the above with `{0,5}`
I've tried them with `$`

Also, the normal pattern.test() seems to work differently than replace.

What am I missing?

Here is a snippet to play with:

```js
$('#ZIP').keyup(function() {
 $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/(\D){0,5}/,""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ZIP"/>
```

After playing with the code for a while, I noticed that `/\D{5}/g` will allow only 5 letters. So I'm sure my lack of expression know-how is preventing me from getting this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may simply do:

```
$('#ZIP').keyup(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,"").slice(0,5));
});
```

Check out the demo below

```js
$('#ZIP').keyup(function(){
 $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,"").slice(0,5));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ZIP"/>
```

Comment: Nice! I can set the maxlength attribute on the <input> element also. But I would like to figure out how to do this with the expression. I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: @Jeremy: if your interest is purely academic, I can understand that, but from practice standpoint it doesn't make sense to stack up some messy regex to catch all the possible tricky inputs where simple string slicing works perfectly fine. Moreover, regex solution will get you those *bouncing back and forth* characters which doesn't seem aesthetic to you ;)

Comment: I agree. And, yes it is purely to see if it can be done, lol. I was just curious!

Comment: Then, right off the top of my head, catch this one: `s.replace(/(\D)|(?<=.{5})./g,'')`, hopefully it gets me accept ;)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I can right-click and paste a non-zipcode into the text

Comment: Yeah bro, you totally got it! Excellent!

Comment: @symlink, your answer is more robust and I like it, but like Yevgen point out, I simply wanted to know how to do it in the regular expression.

Comment: @symlink, dude no need to delete your post, your answer is awesome and could help others out.

Comment: @symlink: just like there's no need to downvote mine due to getting upset ;) , however, I agree with Jeremy it is really nice how it silently ignores invalid input. Undelete and I will gladly upvote. And please remove copy-paste disabling thing ;)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov your code is flawed, I won't delete the comment.

Comment: @symlink: can you be more specific what's wrong with it in your opinion? Would you give some test string that passes through?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I might do this:

```js
function extract5digitZip(str)
{
 // Create a regular expression that can
  // be used to remove all non-digits:
 let rxMatchNonDigits = /[^\d]+/g;

 // Remove all non-digits
 str = str.replace(rxMatchNonDigits,"");

 if (str.length >= 5)
 {
  return str.substr(0,5);
 }
  // If 5 digits can't be extracted
  // return an empty string
 return "";
}
console.log(extract5digitZip("abc75926xyz"));
console.log(extract5digitZip("77036-1234"));
console.log(extract5digitZip("a1b2c3d4e5f6"));
```